# How to smothly move the character controller between x positions like in Subway Surfer in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to replicate the movement from Subway Surfers in Unity but I can't achieve that.

The character is located in the position 0 in the x-axis and when the left button is pressed the player will subtract 3 from the current position, and if the right button is pressed the player will add 3 to the current position making him move between -3,0,3 in the x-axis and all of this keeping the y and z axes unchanged.

I've tried using both Lerp and Slerp but I just couldn't achieve what I wanted. I've come down to a broken code that also changes the y, z-axis what I don't want to do:

```
        var currPos = transform.position;
        var currPosX = currPos.x;

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if (currPosX > -horizontalSteps)
            {
                var newPos = new Vector3(currPosX - horizontalSteps, currPos.y, currPos.z);
                newPos = Vector3.Slerp(currPos, newPos, 3);
                Controller.Move(newPos);
            }
        }
            
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
        {
            if (currPosX < horizontalSteps)
            {
                var newPos = new Vector3(currPosX + horizontalSteps, currPos.y, currPos.z);
                newPos = Vector3.Slerp(currPos, newPos, 3);
                Controller.Move(newPos);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you use Slerp in Update add Time.deltaTime in the 3rd paramter instead of 3. `newPos = Vector3.Slerp(currPos, newPos, Time.deltaTime);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a very simple way

the character have 3 states so let's say we have a state variable (-1 , 0 , 1) for left, mid, and right
, and init with 0
if the player press right `state++`, if press left `state--`

completed if statement

```
if(button.right && state < 1) state++; "move right script";
else if(button.left && state > -1) state-- "move left script";
```

well,
about moving

I prefer `Vector3.MoveTowards()`for smoothly moving and avoid issues

try this example

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class movv : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button right;
    public Button left;
    public float speed;
    private int state = 0;
    void Start()
    {
        Button btn = right.GetComponent<Button>(); 
        btn.onClick.AddListener(delegate { moveright(); }); 
        Button btn2 = left.GetComponent<Button>(); 
        btn2.onClick.AddListener(delegate { moveleft(); }); 

        void moveright()
        {
            if (state < 1) state++;
        }
        void moveleft()
        {
           if(state > -1) state--;
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 x = new Vector3 (state * 3, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        transform.position =  Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, x, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

that's a quick one...

Hint:
this code works when the character position on the x-axis equal to 0

if not,
this is a general example,

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class movv : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button right;
    public Button left;
    public float speed;
    private Vector3 x;
    private int state = 0;
    private int target = 0;
    void Start()
    {
        x = transform.position;
        Button btn = right.GetComponent<Button>(); 
        btn.onClick.AddListener(delegate { moveright(); }); 
        Button btn2 = left.GetComponent<Button>(); 
        btn2.onClick.AddListener(delegate { moveleft(); }); 

        void moveright()
        {
            if (state < 1)
            {
                target = 1;
                x = new Vector3(transform.position.x + target * 3, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                state++;
            } 

        }
        void moveleft()
        {
            if (state > -1) 
            {
                target = -1;
                x = new Vector3(transform.position.x + target * 3, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                state--;
            }
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position =  Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, x, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```